# Soap WS Connection refused

Tags: web-services, soap, https, jax-ws, truststore

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP webserver, I was given a certificate but I get the below exception. 
I did:

```
$openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out certificate.cer -nodes

$keytool -import -alias webserver -file certificate.cer

Certificate was added to keystore
```

I have a junit test that calls the remote server with these JVM options:

```
-ea -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=certificate.cer
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PEM
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pwd

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=certificate.cer
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PEM
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=pwd
```

the remote call is done using:

```
authenticationService.getAuthenticationServiceSoap().authenticateWithPasswordAuth(clientId, username, password);
```

where the client I'm using has got these annotations:

```
@WebServiceClient
public class AuthenticationService extends Service {

and 
@WebEndpoint(name = "AuthenticationServiceSoap")
    public AuthenticationServiceSoap getAuthenticationServiceSoap()
```

I don't do anything else code wise, and I get the below Exception:
I don't even understand if java is trying to use https or no.

> ---[HTTP request - http://..../Soap/AuthenticationService.asmx]--- Accept: [text/xml, multipart/related] Content-Type: [text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8] SOAPAction:
>   ["http://....../AuthenticateWithPasswordAuth"] User-Agent: [JAX-WS RI
>   2.2.4-b01]
>
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)  at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:976)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)